# How can i make it so a change of a IntValue is permanent?

Tags: lua, roblox

So im trying to make a gamepass (developer products to get money via Robux) gui, and while testing it a few times, it worked, until i reached a certain value of around 400,000-500,000 bananas (thats my currency) it stopped working. Also, earlier when making my game, when i purchase something that has costs over 1 million bananas, it appears to decrease, but when i get some banana seeds (sellable item) and sell it, it resets back to before i bought the 1 million banana item (e.g from 1.3 million then i purchase it, then it becomes 300,000, but when the value gets modified (example: via selling seeds) it changes back to before it got bought (1.3 million)) and also im working on a Admin GUI and i wanna make a gui to give money, obviously i knew it wasn't going to work in the first place.

Leaderstats script:
Script name: leaderstats
Script type: server side
Script code:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function()
     local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
     leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

     local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
     coins.Name = "Bananas"

     local resets = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
     resets.Name = "Rebirths"

     local bananaseeds = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
     bananaseeds.Name = "BananaSeeds"
end)
```

My gamepass handler script (ServerScriptService):
Type: server side
Name: DevPrdctHndlr
Code:

```
local mps = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

mps.ProcessReceipt = function(reciptInfo)
 if reciptInfo.ProductId = 1146099164 then
      --[Donate to me!]
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerByUserId(reciptInfo.PlayerId)
        player.leaderstats.BananaSeeds.Value = 
        player.leaderstats.BananaSeeds.Value + 10000
        player.leaderstats.Bananas.Value = 
        player.leaderstats.Bananas.Value + 50000
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
    end
end
```

Buy SmoothPlasticWand script (its a shop gui textbutton):
Type: localscript
Name: BuyScript
Location: game.StarterGui.ShopGui.ShopFrame.SmoothPlasticWand.BuyScript
Code:

```
local Button = script.Parent
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local currency = 
game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats:WaitForChild("Bananas")

Button.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
     if currency.Value >= 1000000 then
  
   
 ReplicatedStorage.ReplicatedWands.SmoothPlasticWand:Clone().Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("Backpack")
    game.Workspace.Musounds.Buy:Play
    currency.Value = currency.Value - 1000000
end)
```

Im sorry if this question is a duplicate, im still a noob at StackOverflow and im sorry if this question isn't detailed enough, i will provide additional details if you want.

Comment: please check the posted code. you're missing quotes. is that only here or in your actual script? you should face errors then

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: My code works fine, its just that it dosent save its value, and resets to before i bought the tool

Comment: you're missing `"` to close `"Rebirths`

Comment: If your talking about some of the code outside of code blocks, then that is a mistake i made in stackoverflow, i put four spaces, but it kept making it look like it was outside the code

Comment: I just said my code works fine, i just made a mistake on typing it in stackoverflow (typing this on my phone, laptop is potato so i cant open firefox and roblox studio at the same time)

Comment: just select the code block and press ctrl + k next time.

Comment: Alright, ill try to paste the code into notepad and try to copy it to stackoverflow next time

Comment: I'll answer your question, its only here, not on the actual script

Comment: you could have simply added it here intead of answering my question in a comment. I'll add it for you...

Comment: I still find you post rather confusing. I suggest you provide a detailed list of what you do, what you expect to happen and what happens instead rather than telling long stories about what used to work earlier. focus on the actual problem. use prints to debug. it should be pretty straigth forward to trace values and what is going on inside your program using a lot of prints

Comment: I'll provide u the game link (I put my dev wand for infinite bananaseeds in starterpack) Game link: https://web.roblox.com/games/6229879051/Banana-Simulator-My-1st-Simulator-Game (to find the issue, click on shop, then scroll down, then click on smoothplasticwand or neonwand)

Comment: Dont worry if it looks messy, i was still in the middle of developing it

Comment: What i did: Make a shop gui and shop script (buy script is a local script) what i expected: a perfectly working shop system, and working gamepass script. I'll try to add prints and i'll notify you ASAP

Comment: sorry I am not interested in running your game. please provide a [mcve]  and stop adding information through comments. improve your actual post! please read [ask].  it is fairly simple to debug errors like this. you do something and using prints you check if everything is working as expected. at one point you will have input A, expected outcome B and actual output C. if you don't know what is going on, that's when you post a question here. I'm out. sorry

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is : do the work on the server.

[The server is the source of truth for all values](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Roblox-Client-Server-Model). When the world is changed with a server [Script](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Script), that change is replicated to out to all players. But when the world is changed with a [LocalScript](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript), that change only appears in that specific player's world.

So when you use the MouseButton1Up handler on your button in a LocalScript, you are only changing the player's local view of that value, and you are not changing the actual source of truth. One fix for this is to use a [RemoteEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Remote-Functions-and-Events) in your LocalScript to signal to the server that there's a change that needs to be made.

So create a RemoteEvent in ReplicatedStorage and name it something like `BuyItem`

In your LocalScript :

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local BuyItem = ReplicatedStorage.BuyItem

local Button = script.Parent
Button.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
     -- tell the server that the player would like to buy the item
     BuyItem:FireServer("SmoothPlasticWand")
end)
```

And then, in a Script somewhere, handle the signal coming from the client:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local BuyItem = ReplicatedStorage.BuyItem

-- set up a price table for items
local prices = {
    SmoothPlasticWand = 1000000,

    -- add more items here
    -- SomeOtherWand = 10,
}

-- listen for the player wanting to buy things
BuyItem.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, itemName)
    -- check that it's a real item
    assert(type(itemName) == "string", "Expected itemName to be a string")
    assert(prices[itemName], "Could not find a price for " .. itemName)

    -- check that the player has enough money
    local itemPrice = prices[itemName]
    local currency = player.leaderstats.Bananas
    if currency.Value >= itemPrice then
        -- give the player their wand
        local wand = ReplicatedStorage.ReplicatedWands[itemName]:Clone()
        wand.Parent = player.Backpack

        -- subtract how much the wand cost
        currency.Value = currency.Value - itemPrice
    end
end)
```

Now, because the server Script is handling the change to `currency.Value`, that change will properly show up for everyone and make the change permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for safety, do something like this to reset it to what it should be. Basically make a variable which captures the value of the currency, then make the currency that same value as a fail-safe

--Put This Right After The Item Is Bought
StoredBananas.Value = coins.Value

--This Goes After The Currency Change When Buying So That It Sets It To The Correct Price After It Glitches Out.

coins.Value = StoredBananas.Value

Comment: StoredBananas.Value = coins.Value