# Roblox script, doesn't work but doesn't show any errors

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a baldi basics fan game in Roblox, and once you pick up the notebook, it checks when if the player has 7 coins (notebooks, placeholder name) and it doesn't work, it doesn't seem to show any errors in the script editor.

I tried this script:

```
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
    plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value = plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value + 1
    script.Parent.Sound:Play()
        script.Parent:Remove()
        game.ServerStorage.artem.Parent = workspace
        game.Workspace.lobby:Stop()
        game.Workspace.artem_passive.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
        if plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value >= 7 then -- this is the part that doesn't work 
                game.Workspace["ready up"]:Play()
                game.Workspace["invisible wall"].CanCollide = false
        end
end)
```

There's also a leaderboard script i added in with, that is working.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
    local f = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    f.Name = "leaderstats"
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", f)
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = 0
end)
```

Comment: Are you ever giving them coins? Where is the code that does that?

Comment: the plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value gives them coins on click

Comment: See if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/65966566/2860267