# How am I supposed to save a value that changed in a local script on the server?

Tags: database, roblox, datastore

The leaderstats are saved on a server script, but I am changing the player's Money value in a local script, and the server doesn't notice that so if the player earns 10 points he sees that he has 10 points more, but for the server, which is saving the leaderstats the points don't change. How can I fix that?

I tried to tell a server script the player and value of their money A.K.A their leaderstats when the player's character is removing, but it didn't work. I didn't provide any code, because the Data Store and leaderstats script work when the value is changed by the server's side, but in my case I have local scripts that change the value by the client's side. Is there a way I can "tell" the server the client's value from their point of view?

Comment: and where is your [mcve]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i make it so a change of a IntValue is permanent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938615/how-can-i-make-it-so-a-change-of-a-intvalue-is-permanent)

Answer (score -1):

The short answer to this is you cannot. Roblox's client-server model, explicitly prevents the player from setting leaderstats.

Further, you should not be added money on the client, this should always be done on the server, with serverside validation. This is to prevent exploiters from altering data and giving themselves an insane amount of money.

I would recommend having a RemoteEvent, that the client fires when it feels it should get money and then the server will check if the request is valid and then add the money to the person's leaderstats.

Comment: how can i have as little as possible remote events for a lot of leaderstats changes?